# Passing multidimensional arrays gives and error

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to pass a multidimensional array to a function. When I try to compile I an getting an error saying

```
[Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'int (*)[2]' for argument '1' to 'void reve(int (*)[2], int)'
```

What is the problem ? What am I doing wrong? Following is the code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int rows=2;
const int cols=2;

const int n = 3;
void reve(int arr[rows][cols],int n){
    int br[3][3],i,j,k,l;
    for(i=n-1,k=0;i>=0,k<n;i--,k++){
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=n-1,l=0;j>=0,l<n;j--,l++)
            br[k][l]=arr[i][j];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            arr[i][j]=br[i][j];
    }
}

int main() {
    int i,j,k,l,ar[3][3],br[3][3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            cin>>ar[i][j];
    int n=3;

    reve(ar,n);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        cout<<ar[i][j];
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please show the complete error given by the compiler.

Comment: `i>=0,k<n` is equal to `k<n`. Did you mean `i>=0 && k<n`?

Comment: THis is what ur error is:  cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'int (*)[2]' for argument '1' to 'void reve(int (*)[2], int)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a 2-d array in a function call, it decays into a pointer type. However, all dimensions but the first one must match exactly.

If the argument type of a function is `int (*arg)[2]`, then, you can't use a variable that is declared as `int var[3][3]` to call the function. `var` decays to a pointer whose type is `int (*)[3]`.

It is confusing at first because it seems to work in case of 1-d arrays.

```
void foo(int arg[10])
{
}

int var[2];
foo(var); // OK
```

That's because the compiler ignores the size of the first dimension of the array. The above definition of `foo` is same as:

```
void foo(int arg[])
{
}
```

and

```
void foo(int* arg)
{
}
```

However, for a multidimensional array, the size of all but the fist dimension must match exactly. Otherwise, they are different types.

Comment: You can either change the function signature or change the variable. You can change `ar[3][3]` to `ar[rows][cols]` to make it work.

Comment: This solved the problem. All correct. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `reve()` function expects an array of [2][2] but you're passing a [3][3] array.

The `ar` array in `main()` is declared as `int ar[3][3]` while it should have been `int ar[rows][cols]`

Answer (score 0):

You have reserved 2 blocks in memory. And in your loop, you are taking it from 2 to 0 that makes it 3. Do the following changes.

```
const int n= 2;
```

And it should work for your program.